# Visual Basic .NET want to make a class file instance in my main module?

Tags: vb.net

How can I create an instance of a class in my main module? I have not been using VB.NET for all that long (Actually about two days) What I want is to create a console application for a test and create classes that are not in the main code file. I can create an instance of the class if it is in the same main module but what I don't know how to do is create a instance if the class is not in the main module.

CLass File:

```
Public Class Class1
    Dim cText As String
End Class
```

Main Module:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim oLine As New Line("a", "b", "c")

        oLine.setYourName = "testName-testName"

        Class1 h As new Class1()  <--Error at this line

        Console.WriteLine(oLine.setYourName)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub


End Module

Public Class Line

    Private mstrLine As String
    Private mstrTest As String
    Friend Text As String

    Public Sub New()
        Console.WriteLine("Zero-Arguement Construtor")
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Value As String)
        Console.WriteLine("One-Arguement Construtor")
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Value As String, ByVal v As String, ByVal a As String)
        Console.WriteLine("Three-Arguement Construtor")
    End Sub

    Public Sub TextFileExample(ByVal filePath As String)
        ' Verify that the file exists. 
        If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) = False Then
            Console.Write("File Not Found: " & filePath)
        Else
            ' Open the text file and display its contents. 
            Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath)
            Console.Write(sr.ReadToEnd)
            sr.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetWord() As String
        Dim astrWords() As String
        astrWords = Split(mstrLine, " ")
        Return astrWords(0)
    End Function

    Property setYourName() As String
        Get
            Return Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Property Line() As String
        Get
            Return mstrLine
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            mstrLine = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    ReadOnly Property Length() As Integer
        Get
            Return mstrLine.Length
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this line**

```
Dim h As New Class1()
```

instead of

```
Class1 h As new Class1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
Class1 h As new Class1()  <--Error at this line
```

to

```
Dim h As New Class1()  <--No more errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing the syntax of C# and VB.NET together a little bit.

In C#, the declaration type of the variable appears before the name of the identifier, like this:

```
Class1 h = new Class1();
```

In VB.NET, you dimension the variable and then the identifier, like this:

```
Dim h As New Class()
```

---

It is also possible to declare/dimension variables and then assign them in a separate line, like this:

C#:

```
Class1 h;
h = new Class1();
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim h As Class1
h = new Class1()
```